# ssl certificate installation on play framework

Tags: tomcat, ubuntu, ssl, playframework, openssl

I am trying to create a new certificate for my **scala play framework** on **ubuntu** but I cannot import my key with keytool. I haven't been able to figure out what is causing it so I thought I'd see here if anyone recognizes my problem.

First I'm creating my private key using command

```
keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA -keystore tomcat.keystore
```

Then I generate my CSR

```
keytool -certreq -keyalg RSA -alias tomcat -file my-csr-file.csr -keystore tomcat.keystore
```

copy and paste the generated CSR into godady

select the tomcat server on godaddy and received godaddy new certification.
I got 3 files:

```
28042ad1aadd20.crt
gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt
gdig2.crt
```

Installing Root and Intermediate Certificates

```
wget https://certs.godaddy.com/repository/valicert_class2_root.crt –no-check-certificate
keytool -import -alias root -keystore tomcat.keystore -trustcacerts -file valicert_class2_root.crt

wget https://certs.godaddy.com/repository/gd_cross_intermediate.crt –no-check-certificate
keytool -import -alias cross -keystore tomcat.keystore -trustcacerts -file gd_cross_intermediate.crt
```

Second intermediate (gd_intermediate.crt):

```
wget https://certs.godaddy.com/repository/gd_intermediate.crt –no-check-certificate
keytool -import -alias intermed -keystore tomcat.keystore -trustcacerts -file gd_intermediate.crt
```

Installing SSL Certificate

```
keytool -import -alias tomcat -keystore tomcat.keystore -trustcacerts -file my-csr-file.csr
```

Here I receive the following error

```
keytool error: java.security.cert.CertificateParsingException: java.io.IOException: ObjectIdentifier() -- data isn't an object ID (tag = 49)
```

Anyone recognize the problem?
or any other way to install godaddy ssl certificate for tomcat server on ubuntu

Comment: Shouldn't the second to last line be importing a `crt` and not a `csr`?

Comment: Say I need to create .crt file . How to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am so stupid,i was trying to add csr instead of crt file

```
keytool -import -alias tomcat -keystore tomcat.keystore -trustcacerts -file my-crt-file.crt
```

Edit : File type is .crt

Comment: I have the same mistake, where is the crt file? i have only my csr.